# How to move to ESM

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I am using [Egg framework](https://eggjs.org/) for my NodeJs(v14.15.4) application

I want to use latest version of `p-debounce` library, [the package is now pure ESM](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-debounce/releases/tag/v3.0.0), Instead of `const pDebounce = require('p-debounce')` I must use `import pDebounce from 'p-debounce'` that not works on EggJs

### If I use import

```js
(node:10636) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
test.js:5
import pDebounce from 'p-debounce'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

### If I use require

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: .\node_modules\p-debounce\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of .\node_modules\p-debounce\index.js from .\test.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from .\node_modules\p-debounce\package.json.
```

### If I add  "type": "module" in the package.json

```
const path = require('path');
             ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I have many `require` in my application and not want to change all to import at the moment

1. What is "type": "module" in the package.json ?
2. How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be overlooking a particular point in [the changelog you linked](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-debounce/releases/tag/v3.0.0):

> If you cannot move to ESM yet, don't upgrade to this version.

As you've pointed out, your application has already progressed significantly, and you have many `require` that you do not want to change at the moment. There is no need to upgrade to the latest version of `p-debounce` at this time, according to your needs.

When you do decide to migrate to ESM format, in order to upgrade individual files one at a time, [you can use the `.mjs` extension to treat the code as an ECMAScript module.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

Answer (score 0):

### ES modules are the future.

**There is a way around in ES modules to require a common.js module. Using `createRequire`**

[WORKING EXEMPLE](https://replit.com/@MHamzaRajput/GiantBeneficialPatterns#index.js)

**axios-curlirize is ES module and axios support both.**

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';

const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const axios = require('axios');

import curlirize from 'axios-curlirize';

curlirize(axios);


const { data } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
console.log(data)
```

**Using ES modules you can use top-level await without function.**